# How to find if any of X letters are in Y word in python

Tags: python, for-comprehension

I want to make a simple python program that goes through a list of words and filters out any words that don't and do contain any of the given letters

```
testword = "young"

def remove_by_letters(words: list, out_letters, in_letters, print_words=False):
    for word in words:
        has_out = [[i for i in list(out_letters) if i in word] for j in list(word) if j in word]
        has_in = any(in_letters in _ for _ in word)
        print(f"Word: {word}, Out:{has_out}, In:{has_in}")

remove_by_letters([testword],"uo", "y")
```

**SIDE NOTE THIS CODE IS NOT THE CODE IN THE ACTUAL PROJECT ITS JUST CODE TO HELP ME FIGURE THIS OUT TO SEE THE [ENTIRE CODE](https://github.com/UnknownCaz/Wordle-Solver)**

The code should print "Word: young, Out:False, In:True"
I want to learn how to use comprehensions and I want to try and implement them here to make the code neater. I'm not super familiar with python comprehensions here so please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking because you're already using comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_by_letters2(words: list, out_letters, in_letters, print_words=False):
  has_out = True
  has_in = True
  
  for word in words:
    if word.find(out_letters) and has_out ==True:
      has_out = False
    if word.find(in_letters) and has_in ==True:
      has_in = False
    print(f"Word: {word}, Out:{has_out}, In:{has_in}")
```

This shall work, but I'm not sure if it is possible in list comprehensions. I'm still looking into it. Do let me know if it works for you.